# $M$ a $\mathbb{Z}$ module. Then, a morphism $f: \mathbb{Z}_{n} \to M$ is well-defined if and only if $nx=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $M$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module and $0 \neq x \in M$. I want to prove that a morphism $f: \mathbb{Z}_{n} \to M$ defined as $f([a])=xa$ for every $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is well-defined if and only if $nx=0$. Guess this exercise is assuming $M$ as a right module, since we defined $f([a])=xa$, meaning that we are multiplying the ring element $a$ from the right.

First, let's prove that $nx=0$. Since $f$ is well-defined and $[n]=[0]$ we obtain $f([n])=f([0])$. But this means that $xn=x0=0$. But what I want to prove is  $nx=0$.

In the same fashion, for the converse I pick $[a], [b] \in \mathbb{Z}_{n}$ such that $[a] =[b]$. But this means $[a-b]=[a]-[b]= [0]$. So I would like to prove $f([a-b])=f([0])$. But first, recall that $[a-b]=[0]$ means that $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$, this is $n \mid a-b$, so there is $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $nk=a-b$. Now on one hand, I have $f([a-b])=x(a-b)=x(nk)=(xn)k$. On the other hand, I obtain $f([0])=x0=0$. So in order to obtain  $f([a-b])=f([0])$ I should affirm $xn=0$. Which is weird since what I need to obtain is $nx=0$.

Is there something about the additive notation over $M$ that would let me affirm $nx=xn$ ? This is troubling me because $M$ is supposed to be a right $\mathbb{Z}$ module, right? Also, is this the only way we can define a morphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{n} \to M$?  Being $M$ a $\mathbb{Z}-$ right module.

Comment: Why $nx=0$?  You are clearly considering $M$ as a *right* $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so that shoul dbe $xn$, not $nx$.

Comment: If $M$ is a right $R$-module and $R$ is commutative, it induces a left $R$-module structure on $M$ by $rm:=mr$. Nevertheless here $xn=x(1+1+\dots+1)=x+x+\dots+x=nx$ for a positive $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, I think the same as you! Im solving exercise $6(a)$ from Bland's Rings and their Mouldes from section $1.5$. There it is written $nx$ so maybe its a typos. What do you think? The same with exercise $6(b)$ I reckon.

Comment: @Berci Thanks Berci!! Maybe the problem as stated with $nx$ instead as $xn$ is not  very correct. But your remark show me it doesnt matter as the additive notation tell us is the same thing. However, is this the only way we can define a morphism from $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ to a right $\mathbb{Z}$ module??

Comment: Actually, $[1]\in\Bbb Z_n$ generates the $\Bbb Z$-module $\Bbb Z_n$ so its image $x:=f([1])\,\in M$ determines the homomorphism $f$ since we must have $f([n])=n\cdot f([x])=xn$ which can also be regarded as a shorthand for $x+\dots+x$ ($n$ pieces). So, any such $x\in M$ for which $xn=0$, uniquely determines a module homomorphism $f$. By the way, $\Bbb Z$-modules are essentially the same as Abelian groups.

Comment: @Berci Again, thanks for your remarks. This is just one part from three in an exercise Im working through. If I dont solve part 2 and 3 by my own I will probably ask for some help tomorrow.